# Vaadin-Datepicker Min/Max limit not working

Tags: datepicker, polymer, vaadin, vaadin-date-picker

I got two Vaadin-datepickers in a Polymer Project. One with a start-date and one with an end-date. I want to make sure that the end-date is always after the start-date. I read the API-Documentation where they say you can use the min max properties.

```
<vaadin-date-picker label="Start date" value="{{item.startDate}}"></vaadin-date-picker>
<vaadin-date-picker label="End date" min="{{item.startDate}}" value="{{item.endDate}}"></vaadin-date-picker>
```

With the above example nothing seems to happen?

I did another test to check if the vars are defined and if maybe the format was incorrect

```
<vaadin-date-picker label="End date" min="2000-01-01" max="2000-12-31" value="{{item.endDate}}"></vaadin-date-picker>
```

I also checked which version I'm using but that's all up-to-date 
`1.1.4`

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: item is just one of my objects in my dom-repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Min/Max limits are not supported in 1.1.4 release.

From GitHub documentation :

https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/releases/tag/v1.2.0-alpha1

Comment: Yeah, the support is coming in 1.2 (out very soon). Sorry for having the documentation already deployed on vaadin.com/docs, that probably causes confusion.

Comment: 1.2 is released now: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/releases/tag/v1.2.0

Answer (score 3):

As @Tomek pointed out, `min` and `max` were added in `1.2.0-alpha1` (not yet released). Your code looks correct and [would work](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RooewE) if using the newer version.

When running `bower install vaadin-date-picker`, Bower installs the latest official release, which is currently `1.1.4`. You could install `1.2.0-beta1` with this:

```
bower install --save vaadin-date-picker@1.2.0-beta1
```

Answer (score 2):

1.2.0-rc1 was also released today. You can install it with bower:

`bower install vaadin-date-picker#1.2.0-rc1`